# Converter moeda no formato 1.000,00

Tags: javascript, ajax

Estou utilizando um script personalizado que imprime o valor da moeda com virgula, porém não esta inserindo ponto no caso de milhar.

Atualmente ele imprime assim: **1000,00**

Preciso que ele imprima dessa forma: **1.000,00**

Segue parte do código responsável pela impressão:

```
pai.find('.valor_original').html(escolha != 1 ? '<strong><span class="strike">R$ '+preco.toFixed(2).replace(".",",")+'</span></strong>' : '<strong>Altere a</strong>');
```

O valor que ele recebe é com ponto: **1000.00**, então ele esta convertendo para virgula. Como devo alterar o `replace` nesse caso?

Preciso saber como modificar nesse script específico.

Comment: Cara, dá uma olhadas nas outras perguntas. O replace que vc está fazendo apenas troca o ponto pela vírgula.